# How to keep a bucket using case statement even if the count for items in that bucket is 0?

Tags: sql

Here's the data table named "**Salary_table**" that i've created for this question:
[image]

So I want to find the number of employees in each salary bucket in each department. the buckets are

```
"<$100" "$100-$200" and ">$200"
```

The desired output is:

[image]

Below is my code for achieving this task:

```
select distinct(st.department) as "Department", 
sb.salary_bucket as "salary range", count(*)
from Salary_table st
Left join (
    select department, employee, case
        when salary < 100 then "<$100"
        when salary between 100 and 200 then "$100-$200"
        else ">$200"
        end 
        as salary_bucket
    from Salary_table
) sb
on sb.employee = st.employee
group by st.department, sb.salary_bucket
order by st.department, sb.salary_bucket
;
```

but my output is a bit short of what im expecting:

[image]

There are TWO problems with my current output:

1. The buckets with 0 employees earning the salary in the bucket range are not listed; I want it to be listed with a value "0"
2. The salary bucket is NOT in the right order, even though I added in the statement "order by" but I think it's b/c its texts so can't really do that.

I would really appreciate some hints and pointers on how to fix/achieve these two issues I've addressed above. Thank you so much!

**what i've tried**

1. I tried use "left join" but output came out the same
2. I tried adding the "order by" clause but doesnt seem to work on text buckets

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? also: `distinct` is **NOT** a function. It always applies to all columns in the select list

Comment: Hi @a_horse_with_no_name, thank you for your response! I am not using any particular DBMS, as I am still learning SQL. I learned using "distinct" from here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp. It is not a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sort of on the right track, but the idea is a bit more complicated.  Use a `cross join` to get all the rows -- the buckets and departments.  Then use `left join` to bring in the matching information and finally `group by` for the aggregation:

```
select d.department, b.salary_bucket,
       count(sb.department) as cnt
from (select '<$100' as salary_bucket union all
      select '$100-$200' union all
      select '>$200'
     ) b cross join
     (select distinct department from salary_table
     ) d left join
     (select department, employee,
             (case when salary < 100 then '<$100'
                   when salary between 100 and 200 then '$100-$200'
                   else '>$200'
              end) as salary_bucket
      from Salary_table
     ) sb
     on sb.department = d.department and
        sb.salary_bucket = b.salary_bucket
group by d.department, b.salary_bucket;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, Thank you so much for your quick answering! I really appreciate it. However, as I am a newbie in SQL, I am not that familiar with "cross join", even though I've read about it and know that its used mostly when finding employee's managers, etc. Can you explain a bit more on the cross join here? and also why use all the union all?

Comment: The `union all` generates the buckets.  The `cross join` generates the rows.  Run the subquery and the `cross join` as independent queries to see what they do.

Comment: Thank you so much! Will play around with it and try my best to understand. But at least when I tried your code, it generates exactly what I wanted! So thank you!